# Can't generate a regex even if it is so simple

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Assume I have this URL

http://server-VM1.test.com:8080/main-app/master/

I need a regex that replaces it to

http://server-VM1.test.com:8080/main-app/

whether there is a slash after master or not !

I have the following pattern

```
 /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/(.*)        /$1
```

but it works only when I add a slash to the end

https://regex101.com/r/8XVPnx/4

.. and help?

Please note that the regex has also to work even if we have more than a slash at the end.

Example ->

http://server-VM1.test.com:8080/main-app/master/

replaces to

http://server-VM1.test.com:8080/main-app/ or http://server-VM1.test.com:8080/main-app/////

Comment: What about [`/[^/]+/?(?:[?#].*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/e0Qybr/1)

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/8XVPnx/1

Comment: @ctwheels not working

Comment: @S.Kablar the problem here is that if we add more than a slash at the end, we still get /master

Comment: @Ziko I updated my comment to include a link, what's not working exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to replace. S.Kablar's regex works well but if we have more than a slash at the end, it fails. my regex in the questions if we have more than a slash, still removes master and adds slashs after main-app which isn't a problem for my app.

Comment: Edit your post and add "more than a slash at the end" thing.

Comment: It is not quite clear. If the subpart you want to keep is at the start, you might try something like `^/([^/]+)(?:/.*)?$` and replace with `/$1` (not sure about the intial `/` and a non-capturing group though).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew check this https://regex101.com/r/8XVPnx/4. your regex is not working too.

Comment: But in mod-rewrite, does the input include the host part? And [here was my test](https://regex101.com/r/kzKISe/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah the input includes everything from http to the end.

Comment: Show htaccess rules.

Comment: Well, it is rather hard to help without clear requirements, probably, [`/\w+(?:/(.*))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/WBdMph/1) could work for you if you need to remove the first subpart that only consists of word chars.

Comment: @sln replaces* sorry

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok your last regex does the job. I would take it as a base to go! Thank you

Comment: I got to give you a -1, not because you aren't clear about what you need, but because you've insinuated the heart of your intent is to match a word `/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/` surrounded by forward slash. This gives rise to the answer you've selected `/\w+(?:/(.*))?$`. There is no correlation of the position of the directory you want to remove. Indeed it is random at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/\w+(?:/(.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WBdMph/1).

**Pattern details**

- `/` - a `/` char
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (letters, digits or `_`)
- `(?:/(.*))?` - an optional occurrence of:

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `(.*)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern) that captures any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

What about this : `(\w+)(/+)?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8XVPnx/8)

also You can Use `(?<=main-app/)[a-zA-Z/]{1,}?$`, this remove everything after **main-app/**

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/8XVPnx/9)

Comment: This one works well but I would go with Wiktor's last comment. I will accept this solution too, thank you