# PHP Regular expression if word comes in last of the sentence

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace matching words in the url:
Ex. https://localhost/user_dafault/admin
here i want to replace "/admin" here if it comes in the last of the url

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't generate a regex even if it is so simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630967/cant-generate-a-regex-even-if-it-is-so-simple)

Comment: What have you done, and how did it go? Also, *where* and *how* do you want to do this replacing: `mod_rewrite` or inside PHP code?

Comment: It needs to be replaced if any other admin user wants to change there admin url like if the url is  'https://localhost/user_dafault/admin' than he can change the admin value from the url like  'https://localhost/user_dafault/backenduser'

Answer (score 0):

Use `$` to specify 'last occurrence' in string, e.g. :

```
<?php
$url = "https://localhost/user_dafault/admin";
echo preg_replace("#\/admin$#","/replacement-text-here",$url);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! it helped me.